# How to create a static image for my shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

So I'm not being able to get the image to my app, I'm using this code:

```
tags$img("bold.png",width = "100px", height = "100px")
```

The problem is the image doesn't appear when the app runs. However the name of the image "bold.png" appears, as well as an empty square where the image was supposed to be at.
Anyone can solve this? 
Thank you so much for any answer

Answer (score 0):

Putting the `tags` inside the `div` may solve the problem like,

```
div(style="display:inline-block",tags$img(src='bold.png', width = "100px", height ="100px")),
```

Note that, the image file has to be stored in the `www` file inside the working directory.